# Tesseract for negative numbers

Tags: c#, numbers, ocr, tesseract, digits

What might I do to improve tesseract accuracy for negative numbers? For whatever reason it just won't detect it correctly, even though the picture is pixel-perfect.

[image: Image in question]

I'm running tesseract 4.1, using LSTM with fast tessdata.
I've assigned **"tessedit_char_whitelist"** to **"-0123456789"** and I'm using segmentation mode **PageSegMode.SingleChar**.

Tesseract is recognizing only the dash symbol and a newline **"-\n"**.